# Carbon changing timezone of parsed datetime string automatically

Tags: php, datetime, php-carbon

I am trying to simply parse a datetime string like "2024-3-3 16:00" and do some other calculations like addHour and do some conditions. The problem is that when I try to parse `2024-3-3 16:00` and return it, it returns `2024-3-3 14:00`. I don't understand how is that possible. the timezone in my `config/app.php` is set to `Africa/Cairo`. what I understand is that it takes this datetime in UTC and converts it to the configuration timezone. Even if I explicitly gave it a timezone like `Carbon::parse('2024-3-3 16:00', 'Europe/London')`, it also returns the same thing. Can someone please explain what is happening?

**Edit**
This code was in the routes folder in user.php, I created a route for testing called /run. I tried using Carbon::parse(...) in blade, it worked fine.

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        return Carbon::parse('2024-3-3 16:00');
    }
}
```

*output*:

`"2024-03-03T14:00:00.000000Z"`

Comment: Try `return Carbon::parse('2024-3-3 16:00')->toDateTimeString();`.

Comment: it works but I need it to be a carbon object so that I can do my calculations and conditions on it @Olivier

Comment: the value is wrong until I convert it into a string

Comment: I see nothing wrong. `2024-03-03T14:00:00.000000Z` is expressed in UTC (that's what the `Z` at the end means).

Comment: so it is expressed in utc, I don't want it to be expressed in UTC, I want it to be expressed in the given timezone, like `Carbon::parse('2024-3-3 16:00', 'Africa/Cairo)` @Olivier

Comment: I want it to stay as it is, I don't want to change it

Answer (score 0):

The answer was very simple I feel dumb. I just had to enter the datetime in UTC

`Carbon::parse('2024-3-3 16:00', 'UTC')`